# How to get mac host IP address from a docker container?

Tags: docker

I want to access host IP address from a docker container on mac. I know how to do that on Linux by using the bridge0 interface. But docker for mac doesn't have bridge0. I tried to use the gateway `172.17.0.1` in a docker container but it doesn't work.

My docker for mac version is `Docker version 1.13.0, build 49bf474`.

I looked at this link `https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22753` but it mentions to create an alias on lo0 interface which I don't want to. Because our project is running inside docker container and I want to provides a general way without changing anything on the host.

Does anyone know how to do that in Mac?

Answer (score 52):

From the Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds) :

> **I WANT TO CONNECT FROM A CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST**
>
> The Mac has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network
> access). From 17.06 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the
> special Mac-only DNS name `docker.for.mac.localhost` which will resolve
> to the internal IP address used by the host.

I think you'll need to upgrade your Docker For Mac version for this to work.

---

**Updated Answer**

it appears this answer has been deprecated and that you should now use `host.docker.internal` per [docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-18030-ce-mac59-2018-03-26](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-18030-ce-mac59-2018-03-26)

Comment: Let me add to my answer - it appears this answer has been deprecated and that you should now use `host.docker.internal` per https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-18030-ce-mac59-2018-03-26

Comment: Instead of adding a comment to your original answer it might be more helpful to edit it because the answer is deprecated and it keeps getting downvotes.